# datatables initizalize two or more times with respect to function call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

i have three select fields on last select onchange event call.(function clas).
First time it runs and datatables initilize but when the second time event runs and function call and datatable again initilize it makes Error. 
i dont know how to set the format or how i can initialize datatable outside the function .
i just want to initilize datatables for once but call ajax every time with respect to function here is my code
And also ajax runs first time automatically with datatable initilization but second time ajax call when event run and function call

```
     function clas(src)
    {

    var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
  "processing":true,
  "serverSide":true,
  "order":[],
   "ajax":{
   url:"requests/add_students/fetch.php",
   type:"POST",
    data: {
          "class_name": 2,
          "class_section": 3,
          "class_session": 4
        }
  },
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
  buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2 ]
                },

            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2 ]
                },


            }

        ],
   "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
  "columnDefs":[
   {
    "targets":[0, 3, 4],
    "orderable":false,
   },
  ],

 });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if datatable exist or not before initialing it. If it is already initialized then no need to to re initiate it. Check below code:

```
function clas(src) {    
            if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#user_data')) {
                var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
                    "processing":true,
                    "serverSide":true,
                    "order":[],
                    "ajax":{
                        url:"requests/add_students/fetch.php",
                        type:"POST",
                        data: {
                            "class_name": 2,
                            "class_section": 3,
                            "class_session": 4
                        }
                    },
                    dom: 'lBfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'copyHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: [1, 2]
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csvHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: [1, 2]
                            },

                        }
                    ],
                    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                            "targets": [0, 3, 4],
                            "orderable": false
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        }
```